# Uploading Files Faster to Google Drive

Tags: hard-drive, ftp, google-drive, upload

I had a question, I'm backing up my photos in RAR file and want to upload to Google Drive. Each RAR file reaching to 400 MB and sometimes that can abort the upload progression (because sometimes my internet connection is poor). So how can I upload this files without any split? FTP also not compatible to Drive (at least on my experience) and FTP sometimes make failures when internet connection is poor.

Comment: There isn’t any other option besides the desktop syncing client and the browser

Comment: What's your benefit of creating a RAR file? And if you add a new photo you create a new RAR and upload it? I assume your files are jpg's so they are already compressed. Why not sync with Google Drive? Just curious.

Comment: I'm uploading the photos to RAR file for encrypting my photo files, for any issue possibility. Also I'm creating a RAR file and compress them as "store", the lightest action.

Comment: Are you putting only a single picture in each RAR? If not, you should to reduce the individual size of each file.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be using Google's latest supported tool for sync'ing with Drive. It is *not* the Drive desktop client, [which has been officially deprecated](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2017/09/drive-file-stream-from-google.html). You can read more about that in the [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/09/21/technology/personaltech/retiring-the-google-drive-desktop-app.html), [The Register](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/09/11/google_deprecates_drive/) and elsewhere.

You have two replacements from Google, **Backup & Sync** or **File Stream**, the latter being available only to G-Suite users. You can download the latest version from [Google](https://www.google.com/drive/download/).

Regarding your problem - failure to upload "large" files over a flaky connection. First, in my experience 400MB is not such a large file. I've encountered this problem only when I get to multiple gigabytes. But perhaps your internet can get too flaky even for that. I suggest you try the following steps:

1. Download the latest offering from Google (see link above) and see if it does a better job than the old Drive client. Note that in my experience Backup & Sync has been more reliable than its predecessor.
2. Try some of the alternative to Google's clients. (Contrary to one of the comments, there are several alternatives.) One that I have experience with is [InSync](https://www.insynchq.com/). I've found it very reliable, speedy and the customer service pretty responsive. However, after 15 days free trial you have to buy a license.
3. Another alternative I explored that looks promising is [odrive](https://www.odrive.com/). I don't have personal experience with it yet. They have a free tier that includes everything you need. FYI, their paid version includes encryption so you wouldn't need to first RAR your pictures.
4. You can find many [additional alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/insync/) at Altenativeto.net - some free and some commercial.

I hope one of those, maybe even Google's latest offering, will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

filezilla pro can upload to google drive.

Comment: You may wish to improve this answer with a link to FileZilla Pro.  Please use proper sentence capitalization.